3D Scan ply without a texture file
I have a 3D scan as ply, without texture file, but with color information of the points. Is it possible to import the file into blender to export a 3D data set e.g. .obj with texture?
In Sculpting mode I can see the colors of the dots, but only in this mode. How can I export the texture from Sculpting mode?
Best regards
Jens
